# Python - Find min, max, and inflection points of normal curve

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, derivative

I am trying to find the locations (i.e., the x-value) of minimum, start of season, peak growing season, maximum growth, senescence, end of season, minimum (i.e., inflection points) in a vegetation curve. I am using a normal curve here as an example. I did come across few codes to find the change in slope and 1st/2nd order derivative, but not able to implement them for my case. Please direct me if there is any relevant example and your help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
## Version 2 code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from  scipy.stats import norm

x_min = 0.0
x_max = 16.0

mean = 8
std = 2

x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)
y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)

# Slice the group in 3
def group_in_threes(slicable):
    for i in range(len(slicable)-2):
        yield slicable[i:i+3]

# Locate the change in slope
def turns(L):
    for index, three in enumerate(group_in_threes(L)):
        if (three[0] > three[1] < three[2]) or (three[0] < three[1] > three[2]):
            yield index + 1

# 1st inflection point estimation
dy = np.diff(y, n=1) # first derivative
idx_max_dy = np.argmax(dy)
ix = list(turns(dy))
print(ix)

# All inflection point estimation
dy2 = np.diff(dy, n=2) # Second derivative?
idx_max_dy2 = np.argmax(dy2)
ix2 = list(turns(dy2))
print(ix2)

# Graph
plt.plot(x, y)
#plt.plot(x[ix], y[ix], 'or', label='estimated inflection point')
plt.plot(x[ix2], y[ix2], 'or', label='estimated inflection point - 2')
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend(loc='best');
```

Comment: I think the solution will depend on the real data, for instance the level of type of noise... If the curves looks like a Gaussian, why not fit a Gaussian (using [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)), and then compute the wanted features from the mean and variance obtained? How the features, i.e. start of season, peak growing season, maximum growth, senescence, end of season..., are "mathematical" definited?

Comment: Thanks @xdze2! The curve I am using is just representative. I am mainly looking for the list of vertices that precede inflection points in a curve. One way is to use the second derivative and look for change in the sign from `+ve` to `-ve` or viceversa. I just dont know how to do  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple and not robust method to find the inflection point of a non-noisy curve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from  scipy.stats import norm

x_min = 0.0
x_max = 16.0

mean = 8
std = 2

x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)
y = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)

# 1st inflection point estimation
dy = np.diff(y) # first derivative
idx_max_dy = np.argmax(dy)

# Graph
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[idx_max_dy], y[idx_max_dy], 'or', label='estimated inflection point')
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend();
```

The actual position of the inflection point is `x1 = mean - std` for a Gaussian curve.

For this to work with real data, they have to be smoothed before looking for the max, by applying for example  a simple moving average, a [gaussian filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.html) or a [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter) which can directly output the second derivative... the choice of the right filter depends on the data

Comment: Thanks @xdze2! Good to know that [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy.signal.savgol_filter) filter outputs second derivative and as you said, the filtering depends on the data. Here is something that i am looking for (Version 2 code above), not sure if I did the second derivative part right?